# very non-trivial template friend declaration

Tags: c++, templates, friend

```
class Foo
{
    template <typename T> friend void T::persist(void);
    int test;
};

class Bar
{
    Foo foo;
    void persist(void) { foo.test = 42; } // fails
}
```

With this, I hope that persist() member method of every class which defines it will be a friend of foo. The strange friend line compiles, but seems to do nothing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, you can only befriend free functions, classes, and templates thereof. You cannot befriend just one member function out of a class.

Comment: @KerrekSB You can, just not if that class is not specified; it's not going to work with templates.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. You cannot befriend a member of *all* types, and your *template-friend* declaration is ill-formed. There is no *template* in:

```
class Foo
{
    template <typename T> 
    friend void T::persist(void);

    int test;
};
```

Note that the *friend* declaration is not a template. You can *befriend* a template function or class, but there is neither of them in the code above.

A simple workaround would be to create a helper class from which you derive and provides the accessor:

```
class Foo {
   friend class FooAccessor;
   int value;
};
class FooAccessor {
protected:
   void write( Foo& f, int value ) {
     f.value = value;
   }
};
class FooUser : private FooAccessor {
   Foo f;
   void persist() {
      write( f, 42 );
   }
};
```

But you might want to revisit the design and look for alternatives, note that making fields `private` and then allowing every other class to access them through a `friend` declaration is not much better than just having the fields public. If you care to explain what you are trying to achieve, someone might be able to help you.